# One word for "any way around it"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary, synonyms

Let us say I frame a sentence as follows:

> Is there any way around this problem?

I want to convey the feeling that bypass, or trick without actually using the problem, without actually dealing with it.

P.S.: It may so happen that my actual sentence does not convey this feeling either. I am learning English and am new to it.

Comment: Do you want *circumvent* (literally, "go around")?

Comment: yup. Heard this word before but forgot. Couldn't remember so asked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew suggested a good word choice to use in an alternative to your example sentence, which would be something like this:

**Can the problem be circumvented?**

or

**Is there a way to circumvent the problem?**

As for a one word substitute for "any way around it", you might consider **alternative**.

Your sentence becomes **Is there an alternative to this problem?**

I would suggest a slight modification of this, though, which might not exactly answer your question:

**Is there an alternative to addressing/facing this problem?**

Comment: Though not related to the problem, but I would like to ask that in the last sentence should we use "addressing" or "address". Why or why not.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: Definitely addressing, because the construct is "an alternative to + noun phrase". Therefore you use the ing-form (the gerund, if you will), which acts like a noun

Answer (score 2):

Is there a [workaround](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/workaround) for this problem?

> [workaround](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work-around) *- a plan or method to circumvent a problem **without eliminating it**.*

(emphasis mine - I don't think other alternatives cover OP's *without actually dealing with it*).

Answer (score 1):

You might try [*dodge*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dodge).

> **dodge** *n.*
>   2. An ingenious expedient intended to evade or trick.

Answer (score -2):

Sidestep.

Has sense of avoidance without resolution, as requested.

- "Can we sidestep this problem?"

---

Suggestions?

Alternatives?

Help!!!

Exit strategy?

Plan B?

Then what?   / Now what?

Next?  / Next please ...

---

3 words, but may spawn ideas. Or not:

[Shikata ga nai!](http://buddhistchurchesofamerica.org/%E2%80%9Cshikata-ga-nai%E2%80%9D)   仕方がない

Can be used several ways but as an affirmation it may be appropriate.

Used in Kim Stanley Robinson's marvellous Red/Green/Blue Mars series as ~= "There is no other way". ~= Let's do it. Let's find a way. ...